# Hidden token management in antlr3

Tags: antlr3

I am using Antlr3.

```
print a;




print b;
```

This is my input file(Stored in DB) to the parser.And in lexer I kept the newline(\n) in hidden channel.So the parser will ignore all the newlines(\n).After executing it when I fetch the input file (from DB) it will change like

```
print a;
print b;
```

My new lines(\n) are missing!!!...How can I retrieve these newlines(\n)

Answer (score 1):

The token stream still has all of them. Simply iterate over all the tokens and you will see your newlines in the loop. Each token comes with a token index, which is the index in the token stream. So, when you see 2 normal tokens with indices that include a gap you know there are hidden tokens and you can retrieve them via your token stream.

Comment: Thank You...But then how can i  retrieve this hidden tokens?Actually when i use "CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);" i will not get the hidden tokens !Right?

Comment: No, that just creates the token stream. But now call `tokenStream.fill();` and `tokenStream.getTokens();` which will return you all the tokens.

Comment: I am regenerating the script based on the tree (Generated by the parser) . I can collect the hidden tokens . But while regenerating the script, after which tree node this hidden token to be added ? How can i relate the tree node and hidden tokens?

Comment: Each token comes with a token index (the position in the input token stream). Use that to find the relationship between the individual tokens.